# sort array of objects by property in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like:

```
[
 {date: "2016-01-07T15:01:51+00:00", text: "Lorem ipsum"}, 
 {date: "2016-22-08T15:04:36+00:00", text: "dolor"},
  // etc.
]
```

How's the best way to sort these by the date property? I'm already mapping this array to a react component, so any solution that works within the map function I guess would be preferred, but not essential.

I'm trying to use the `sort()` method at the moment, but can't work how to feed it the date property.

Comment: Since you have ISO dates, it's safe to compare them as strings, use `date1.localeCompare(date2)` in your sort callback.

Comment: ^ `arr.sort((a,b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date))`

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer, unless it's a mistake in the formatting, `"2016-22-08T15:04:36+00:00"` is an invalid date format in javascript. Notice `new Date("2016-22-08T15:04:36+00:00")` outputs `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a custom sort function:

```js
var data = [{
  date: "2016-07-01T15:01:51+00:00",
  text: "Lorem ipsum"
}, {
  date: "2016-02-22T15:04:36+00:00",
  text: "dolor"
}, {
  date: "2015-08-22T15:04:36+00:00",
  text: "test"
}]


var result = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var date1 = new Date(a.date);
  var date2 = new Date(b.date);
  console.log(date1, date2);
  return (+date1 - +date2);
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @georg, what is the difference between `return (a-b)` and `return (a>b)`. Isn't sort considers `-ve` value as false and `+ve` value as true? I may be wrong. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: You have to return -1, 0, or 1 from the sort callback, not true/false.

Comment: @georg Thanks, what do the -1, 0, or 1 values correspond to?

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer I guess less than, equal and greater than.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer: when comparing a to b, return -1 (or any negative) if a < b, +1 (or any positive) if a > b, and 0 if they are equal, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort